# Disable ionic console colors

Tags: ionic-framework

The `ionic` shell tool uses colours by default which makes the output unreadable in a black-on-white console (KDE konsole on Ubuntu).

Is there an option to disable the colours, i.e. use the default text colour only?

Answer (score -1):

If you look into the ionic sh you will see that they Using Node.js chalk.

you can start your command with parameters or set a global environment variable:

https://github.com/chalk/supports-color#info

Comment: for completness: _ionic [COMMAND] --no-color;_ or _export FORCE_COLOR=0_